# Pass varargs from Java code to SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, jpa-2.0

I need to bind at maximum 8 variables. Each one of them could be **null**.
Is there any recommended way to achieve this? I know that I could simply check for **null**, but this seems tedious.

**Additional details**:
I'm going to call this sql from java code. It may be written using ***JPA 2.0 Criteria API***, but most likely it's going to be a native query. The database is ***Oracle 10g***, so I think I could make use of ***PL/SQL*** as well.

**Edit1:**
Maybe the title is a bit misleading, so I'll try to elaborate.
The resulting SQL would be something like:
`...

WHERE var1 = :var1

AND var2 = :var2

...

AND var = :var8`
Now I need to bind parameters from java code in the way like:
`nativeQuery.setParameter("var1", var1)

...

nativeQuery.setParameter("var8", var8)`
Some parameters could be null, so there is no need to bind them. But I see no way I can omit them in SQL.

**Edit2:**
I'm expecting to see SQL or PL/SQL procedure in your answers (if it's ever possible without **null** checking).
In fact, all of these variables are of the same type. I think it's not possible to find a solution using ANSI SQL, but maybe there are some PL/SQL procedures which allow to work with varargs?

Comment: Why is it tedious to check for null, if it's only for 8 variables?

Comment: @home, because apart from that, the logic in SQL will be quite complicated, and I don't want to get things worse by adding boilerplate null-checking

Comment: Understood... given your example above you will have to check for `null` latest in the procedure. So why not simply set the null values from java without checking?

Comment: @home, I am looking for some way to avoid null-checking in SQL. So that in the WHERE clause I would check only those parameters that were actually bound.

Comment: Ok, so you ask about the SQL code and not the Java code, right? If so I'm not aware of a solution :-)

Comment: @home, "you ask about the SQL code and not the Java code" - that's correct. Sorry for not making it clear in the question.

Comment: what is a problem with 'WHERE (:par1 IS NOT NULL AND par1=:par1')? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a criteria query is appropriate in this case, because if I understood correctly, you need to construct the SQL query dynamically. If all the variables except var1 are null, the where clause would be

```
where var1 = :var1
```

and if all variables except var2 and var5 are non null you would have

```
where var2 = :var2 and var5 = :var5
```

Is that right?

If so, then do what you plan to do, and construct the query dynamically using a criteria query. Something like this must be done:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
Predicate conjunction = builder.conjunction();
if (var1 != null) {
    conjunction = builder.and(conjunction,
                              builder.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.var1),
                                            var1));
}
if (var2 != null) {
    conjunction = builder.and(conjunction,
                              builder.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.var2),
                                            var2));
}
...
criteria.where(conjunction);
```

Comment: yes you understood me correct, and I was going to solve it in the similar way. But the query itself is going to be quite complicated (here I demonstrated only the little part of the problem) and I think that I'll be forced to use Oracle-specific keywords, such as `CONNECT BY` (to make self joins). Therefore it will be hard-coded in orm.xml and I'm going to use it as a NativeQuery. And I'm afraid there is no way to add a Predicate to native query.

Comment: Then you'll have to build the query dynamically using String concatenation, and bind each non-null parameter once the query is built.

Comment: Eventually I ended up using String concatenation to build the dynamic query. I guess there is no other, more elegant solution. I thought, maybe there are certain PL/SQL procedures that make working with varargs easy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the type of the objects you want to pass. So in this example I'm considering you will pass **Object**.

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testMyMethod() {
    List<Object> testList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    testList.add("1");
    testList.add("2");
    testList.add(3);

    myMethod(testList);
}

public void myMethod(List<Object> limitedList) {
    final int MAX_SIZE = 2;
    if (limitedList.size() > MAX_SIZE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size exceeded");
    }
    //my logic
}
```

In this example I'm passing the arguments as a List of Objects but you could use array (**varargs**) or another type of collection if you need to. If the client sends me more than the expected objects it will throw an **IllegalArgumentException**.

Also if you don't want to throw an exception you could just continue and iterate the list to bind the parameters but using the list size or MAX_SIZE as your limit. For example:

```
public void myMethod2(List<Object> limitedList) {
        final int MAX_SIZE = 2;

        int size = MAX_SIZE;
        if (limitedList.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
            size = limitedList.size();
        }

        //Iterate through the list
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Object obj = limitedList.get(i);
            //Logic to bind the obj to the criteria.            
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I was actually expecting to see SQL-query or PL/SQL procedure. See the edit.